# Program that verifies if a word is in a file and prints the number of the line and the line itself

Tags: c

As the title indicates I'm trying to make a program that verifies if a word is in a file and prints the number of the line and the line itself. The exercise tells us to use the function strstr.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define DIM_WORDS 1000

int main(void)
{
    char word[DIM_WORDS]={'\0'};
    char textname[DIM_WORDS]={'\0'};
    char stringtoread[DIM_WORDS]={'\0'};
    char line[DIM_WORDS]={'\0'};
    char* verify;
    FILE* fp=NULL;
    int ret=0 , num=0;

    do{
        printf("Introduza o nome do ficheiro e a palavra a procurar\n");
        // Lê ambas as informações e guarda-as numa string
        fgets(stringtoread, DIM_WORDS, stdin);
        // Separa as duas informações em 2 strings
        ret=sscanf(stringtoread, "%s %s", textname, word);
    }while(ret!=2);


    fp=fopen(textname, "r");

    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: That file doesn't exist or could not be open\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp))
    {

        verify = strstr(word, line);

        if(verify!=NULL)
        {
            printf("The word was encountered in line %d\n", num);
            printf("%s", line);
        }

        num++;

    }


    fclose(fp);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define DIM_WORDS 1000

int main(void)
{
    char word[DIM_WORDS]={'\0'};
    char textname[DIM_WORDS]={'\0'};
    char stringtoread[DIM_WORDS]={'\0'};
    char line[DIM_WORDS]={'\0'};
    char* verify;
    FILE* fp=NULL;
    int ret=0 , num=0;

    do{
        printf("Introduza o nome do ficheiro e a palavra a procurar\n");
        fgets(stringtoread, DIM_WORDS, stdin);
        ret=sscanf(stringtoread, "%s %s", textname, word);
    }while(ret!=2);


    fp=fopen(textname, "r");

    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: That file doesn't exist or could not be open\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp))
    {

        verify = strstr(word, line);

        if(verify!=NULL)
        {
            printf("The word was encountered in line %d\n", num);
            printf("%s", line);
        }

        num++;

    }


    fclose(fp);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

I tried my program with a file text.txt and trying to find the word file:

A text file (sometimes spelled "textfile": an old alternative name is "flatfile") is a kind of computer file that is structured as a sequence of lines of electronic text.

A text file exists within a computer file system.

The end of a text file is often denoted by placing one or more special characters, known as an end-of-file marker, after the last line in a text file.

Such markers were required under the CP/M and MS-DOS operating systems.

On modern operating systems such as Windows and Unix-like systems, text files do not contain any special EOF character.

"Text file" refers to a type of container, while plain text refers to a type of content. Text files can contain plain text, but they are not limited to such.

At a generic level of description, there are two kinds of computer files: text files and binary files.[1]

---

Problem is my program is not printing anything. 
I think the problem might be here:

```
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp))
    {

        verify = strstr(word, line);

        if(verify!=NULL)
        {
            printf("The word was encountered in line %d\n", num);
            printf("%s", line);
        }

        num++;

    }
```

Since if I remove most of the code just to print all the lines of the file it prints them:

```
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)
        printf("%s", line);
```

Can someone help me to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got this backwards

```
verify = strstr(word, line);
```

you're searching for line in word when it should be

```
verify = strstr(line, word);
```